# Recuperar acesso administrativo de super usuário Joomla que por má configuração na ACL deixou de ser administrador?

Tags: joomla

`Joomla`, desde a versão 1.6, permite um nível de acesso de usuário complexo, e, diferente das versões anteriores aonde era possível setar apenas por um papel de usuário (super administrador, gerente, autor...) passou a permitir permissões granulares. Isto é, por acidente, seria possível transformar um usuário que tem permissões de super administrador não acessar mais administração, e é extremamente complicado reverter isso ao alterar direto no banco de dados.

**Como fazer para resolver essa situação emergencial e permitir que um usuário não administrador tenha acesso temporário como se fosse super administrador**?

No caso, sabe-se a senha do usuário, porém ele perdeu permisão de acesso. É diferente dos processos de resetar senha de super administrador vua alteração no banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um modo de tornar um usuário comum em um super administrador temporário, bem como tornar um ex-super administrador. Ele exige acesso aos FTP do seu servidor.

**Este mesmo modo também pode servir caso você tenha perdido a senha de super administrador mas saiba a senha de um usuário comum, e apenas quer entrar na administração do seu site e resetar por ela sua senha anterior**.

1. Via FTP, acesse a raiz do seu site. Ela terá um arquivo `configuration.php`. Se necessário, altere as permissões de arquivo para 644 ou não vai poder alterar o arquivo.
2. Baixe o arquivo para seu computador, faça uma cópia de segurança além da que você irá editar.
3. No início do arquivo, logo depois da linha que contém class `JConfig {`, adicione o seguinte `public $root_user = 'username'`; onde username é o nome de usuário da conta que ter tornar provisoriamente um super administrador.
4. Faça o upload do arquivo editado, e sobrescreva o arquivo anterior.
5. Com o usuário e senha da conta que definiu como super administrador, autentique-se na area administrativa do seu Joomla, e resolva o problema que passou. Se removeu permissões de acesso, adicione-as novamente. Se esqueceu a senha de outro usuário e usou um usuário regular para acessar a administração e resetar sua senha anterior, faça isso.
6. Repita os passos de edição do arquivo `configuration.php`, e remova a linha que permitiu acesso temporário como super administrador.
7. Volte as permissões de acesso do arquivo `configuration.php` a exatamente como estava antes, provavelmente 444. Isso impede que em uma hospedagem compartilhada uma pessoa que saiba o local aonde está este arquivo leia o conteúdo dele.